# Strange behavior of Aptana 3 Studio, can't format the code

Tags: eclipse, ide, aptana, aptana3

I am finding a very strange behavior of Aptana 3 Studio.

If I open a php file (a file take from a Word Press template) and try to do **Source ---> Format** it give me the following error message:

**Unable to format. There are fatal syntax errors in the script**

This thing it is very strange because if I try to open the same file with Eclipse Indigo (Eclipse for PHP) and I try to do **Source ---> format** it work without any problem !!!

Why? can I do to solve in Aptana?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Do you have a code block split by php tag, something like `<?php if (true) { ?> <p>hello</p> <?php } ?>`. I think is a bug in the formatter.